# How do I install Inventel UR056g usb wifi?

Tags: wireless, prism, firmware

I am am using a Inventel UR054g (R01) usb wireless adaptor on my desktop. I had quite trouble setting it up but after installing ndiswrapper and prism2 drivers I got it up and running.

However, I need to run in the command line the following to get it started;

```
sudo dhcpcd wlan0
```

- I want this top start automatically when I restart the PC.
- Further, I aslo want this connection to be available to other users.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you remove the network manager? How did you tell the wifi what network to connect to? Did you edit a file to do it or follow some arcane online guide?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I did not remove the network manager and yes I followed an arcaic guide, I think. Further, I did edit a file to specify the network auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-essid ADW-4401 from /etc/network/interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your device is already supported in 10.10 by the `p54usb` driver, you just need to download the firmware for the UR05g device. Using ndiswrapper and the windows driver isn't recommended unless you absolutely have no other choice.

See this page http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/p54

I did a lot of research on the UR05g and it looks like a typical prism2. Firmware for you device [is available](http://daemonizer.de/prism54/prism54-fw/) and version 2.5.2.0 should be used as it's the version shipped with the ur054g windows driver. Save the firmware to `/lib/firmware/isl3887usb` by using this command:

```
sudo wget daemonizer.de/prism54/prism54-fw/fw-usb/2.13.1.0.lm87.arm -O /lib/firmware/isl3887usb
```

Firstly revert the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, this file shouldn't be changed unless you know exactly why it should and changing it can kill the automatic network-manager and makes everything manual. It should look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Remove the `ndiswrapper` package using apt get `sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper`

Now add to the /etc/modules file on it's own line `p54usb` this will force the driver to load on boot.

If this fails, please report back here the contents of the log file /var/log/dmesg and paste in to http://paste.ubuntu.com (you have to share the link it gives you here)

Comment: Thank you again for the reply. Maybe I am missing the point here,is the driver already part of 10.10? How do I remove and undo ndiswrapper? What should the /etc/network/interfaces file contain?

Comment: See my edit for what it should look like.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please explain this? Remove ndiswrapper from /etc/modules and add p54usb instead. Mine is under etc/ndiswrapper and not etc/modules. How do I add p54usb?

Comment: Does my new edits make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, but my path to ndiswrapper is not the same as the one your are quoting and I just want to get some clarity on that.I really do appreciate your time and assistance!

Comment: rebooted it still did not connect automatically I still had to go terminal to run the dchcp cmd on wan0. og from var/log/dmesg "[19.017315] phy0: p54 detected a LM86 firmware
[19.017330] phy0: FW rev 2.5.2.0 - Softmac protocol 3.0
[19.017338] phy0: you are using an obsolete firmware. visit http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/p54 and grab one for "kernel >= 2.6.28"!
[   19.017351] phy0: cryptographic accelerator WEP:YES, TKIP:YES, CCMP:no
[19.017361] usb 1-2: wrong firmware, please get a firmware for "ISL3887" and try again.
[19.017473] p54usb: probe of 1-2:1.0 failed with error -22

Comment: Can you tell me if you did anything to resolve the issue above so I can improve the answer? And can you mark my answer as answering your question so others will know what to do? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of this, "sudo wget http://daemonizer.de/prism54/prism54-fw/fw-softmac/2.5.2.0.arm -O /lib/firmware/isl3887usb" I used this one "sudo wget http://daemonizer.de/prism54/prism54-fw/fw-usb/2.13.1.0.lm87.arm -O /lib/firmware/isl3887usb" beeing the firmware for my kernel 2.6.28. Apart from that nothing more, thanks again!